# Try to understand the Objective-C block example

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I read some Objective-C code example, and found some code which uses "block" in the the code. I simplify the example a bit so that it is easy to describe.

Given a block in Objective-C

```
 (void)(^myblock)(int num) = ^{
   //do something
}

// somewhere in the code

if(myblock) myblock(3);

// do something
```

My question:

What is the `if(myblock)` here?

From the protocol of the block which is return `void`

I would like someone can explain what is the `if(myblock)` here for?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Your example is syntactically incorrect. It should be:

```
void(^myblock)(int num) =  // No parenthesis around void
^{ 
  //do something
}
```

To your Q:

While it is legal to send a message to a `nil` object reference, it is illegal to call a `NULL` block pointer. Please, keep in mind that blocks are an extension to (plain) C and such a call would be a dereference of a `NULL` pointer, which is illegal in C. Therefore such a code would cause a NULL pointer exception. (On OS X `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`):

```
void(^myblock)(int num) = NULL;
myblock(3);
```

Obviously the developer of the snippet could not guarantee that `myblock` is different from `NULL`, so he has to check for it. (Or he is simply afraid of this possibility. In such a case I would prefer to have an exception or at least a log message. However, you find that kind of code fuses, that makes things worse instead of better, many, many times.)

Answer (score 0):

It simply tests if myblock is not nil

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LuísRamalho Yes it does. It may be an incredibly short, and not massively helpful answer, but it certainly _does_ directly answer the question: "What is the `if(myblock)` here?"

Answer (score 0):

`myblock` is a pointer to the lambda function in modern terminology, it's just kind of hidden by the opaque syntax ObjC uses.

So the `if` tests if the pointer isn't `nil`. Whether or not that makes sense or if it's superfluous depends on the missing code. Maybe it overwrote the pointer to `nil` depending on some condition.